# Does Allah have idols or pictures?

Tags: allah, shirk

I live in a country where there are a lot of idols. Is it possible that Allah may have revealed himself to a nation before us and that they made idols or pictures of his attributes? Is it disbelief if one believes this even if he does not worship idols?

Answer (score 4):

Allah can not be seen by people in this life:

> #### لا تدركه الأبصار
>
> Vision perceives Him not
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:103](https://quran.com/6/103)</sup>

> #### لن تراني
>
> You cannot see Me
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:143](https://quran.com/7/143)</sup>

Also see [Quran 42:51](https://quran.com/42/51?translations=20).

There is nothing in existence that has any resemblance to Allah:

> #### ليس كمثله شيء
>
> There is nothing like unto Him
>
> <sup>— [Quran 42:11](https://quran.com/42/11)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No one has ever seen Allah and it is not allowed to portray him in any way. The reason is that he is beyond the grasp of our imagination and cannot be perceived with our senses.

In fact, believing in the Almighty Allah (or paradise or hell which we have not seen at all nor we can imagine them accurately) is one of the foremost part of faith (Imaan). As said in the beginning of the Quran (Yu'minoom bilghayb), the believers believe in the existence of that which is beyond the perceptions.

Thus, in short, which cannot attribute any picture or idol to Allah. It's a shirk and extremely loathsome act for anyone let alone for a Muslim.

To recognize Allah, we should understand his attributive names. It's part of the understanding of Islam.

Comment: Is it shirk to say that someone has seen Allah? is it shirk if we say that the Prophets or pious people may have seen Allah in their dreams or were blessed with his image in their imagination?